# Zend routing issue with dynamic segment

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-route

I'm working on a Zend project and I have some issues with the router/routes.

I want the have these URLs:

1. www.mydomain.tld/contact/person
2. www.mydomain.tld/contact/person/formsend
3. www.mydomain.tld/contact/person/id

The third segment in the URL will be a fixed text "formsend" or it will contain an ID, which is a number like '123456789'.
URL 1 and 3 should both execute the `indexAction()`, URL 2 must execute the `sendAction()`.

Now I have these route's setup to get URL 1 and 2 working:

```
return array( 
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
        'contact' => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/contact[/][:dns]',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'project\Controller',
                    'controller' => 'Contact',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'send' => array(
                    'type' => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '[/[:action[/]]]',
                        'defaults' => array(
                          'action' => 'send'
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
             ),
        ),
```

I have no idea how I must change my routes so I would be able to have segment_3 inside the `indexAction()`. What do I need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me you only need two routes:

First define `/contact/:type/formsend`, then `/contact/:type[/:id]`.

You can make them children of a top-level (non-terminating) `/contact` or `/contact/:type` route, or not.

Comment: The person part in the URL is also a variable. Only contact is fixed.